# client- server communication with basic fifo, send acknowledgment to client from server after message received

Tags: c, unix

I want the server to send an acknowledgment message to the client once it recieves the message from client. 
I am trying to get the message be printed on client side

server.c

```
  // This is the server
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
   int fd;
  char ch;

unlink("../myserver"); // delete it if it exists  

      if(mkfifo("../myserver", 0777)!=0)
    exit(1);

      while(1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Waiting for a client\n");  

    fd = open("../myserver", O_RDONLY);  
    fprintf(stderr, "Got a client: ");  


        if(read(fd, &ch, 1) == 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "%c ", ch);
        close(fd);
    }
  }
}
```

client.c

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
  int fd;
char ch;
char reply[100];

while((fd=open("../myserver", O_WRONLY))==-1){  
    fprintf(stderr, "trying to connect\n");  
    sleep(1);
}

printf("Connected: type in data to be sent\n");  

while((ch=getchar()) != -1) // -1 is CTRL-D
    write(fd, &ch, 1);  

close(fd);

while(fd = open("../myserver", O_RDONLY));  
    fprintf(stderr, "received message\n");
 }
```

Comment: Please update the title to describe the problem in a way that captures the issue. As written, the title does nothing to give a clue as to what the question is about, which will reduce the number of people willing to click through to look at it.

Comment: `ch` should be an `int`. `getchar()` returns an `int`.

Comment: for the server to send an acknowledgment message to the client once it recieves the message from client, open it in O_WRONLY mode after receiving a non-empty string from client.

Comment: 1) please include the `#include` statements for each of the posted code sequences so we can reproduce the problem.  2) please indicate exactly what the problem is.  3) for ease of readability and understanding, consistently indent the code,  Indent after every opening brace.  Unindent before every closing brace.  Strongly suggest each indent level is 4 spaces,

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`  Since neither of the parameters are used, this will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  Suggest using the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: there is no code in the client to receive any message from the server!

Comment: when calling C library functions, like `open()`, `read()`, `write()` and `close()`  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding statements like: `fprintf(stderr, "trying to connect\n");`  strongly suggest calling `perror()` as that function will output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`